# How to use the javascript getPeerUrl() function in Sharepoint 2013 client object model?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-clientobject

I want to use this function 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj954403.aspx
to get the french url from the english url (I can't just simply change the en to fr and vice versa).

But I am having trouble with the function. It seems to give me `0` instead of the actual url.

This is my code

```
function VariationHandler2() {


    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var site = ctx.get_site();
    var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();
    var webProperties = rootWeb.get_allProperties();

    ctx.load(site);
    ctx.load(rootWeb);
    ctx.load(webProperties);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(

        function() {
            var varLabelsListId = webProperties.get_item('_VarLabelsListId');

            var labelsList = rootWeb.get_lists().getById(varLabelsListId);
            var labelItems = labelsList.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

            ctx.load(labelItems);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(

                function() {
                    var url = rootWeb.get_serverRelativeUrl();

                    var object = SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(ctx, "/en/Pages/default.aspx", "fr");
                    alert(object);
                    alert(object.get_value());
                    alert(JSON.stringify(object));

                },
                function() {
                }
            );
        },
        function() {
        }
    );  
}
```

but I am not getting any useful results. Does anyone know how to get it to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following code to a Content Editor on a publishing page in a site with variations and it worked:

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.publishing.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(VariationHandler, "sp.js"); 
});

function VariationHandler() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(VariationHandler2, "SP.publishing.js"); 
}


function VariationHandler2() {
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var object = SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(ctx, "/en/Pages/default.aspx", "fr");
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(

            function() {
                alert(object.get_value());
            }
        );  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: yes, I got the solution from my post here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148078/how-to-use-the-csom-sp-publishing-variations-getpeerurl-method#148080